# Spring multiple HandlerMethodArgumentResolver per path

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have the following question. Is it possible to add multiple custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` for different paths?

For example I want to a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` that does A for `/myapi/someMapping1/` and a different one that does B for `/myapi/someMapping2/`.

I know that a similar behavior is possible for `HandlerInterceptor` but I would like to know if this is available for `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` too.

Comment: Did you solve in the end? Might work by checking the enclosing class or by checking the method mapping value using MethodParameter.

Comment: @LppEdd you can check my response below. I did not move forward with this approach but I think it can be done by inspecting the URI of the request. Haven't tried this so this is just an idea.

Comment: Yeah the URI is definitely inspectable. As I wrote last week you can even access the mapping annotation via MethodParameter#getMethodAnnotation. Than you can get the value.

Comment: Btw, are you using Spring in a constant manner? If so let me know. It might come handy to share ideas before posting to StackOverflow. I'm developing over Spring 4.3.3 as of now.

Comment: I've lost you a bit. What do you mean by 'constant manner'?

Comment: As your primary development tool.

Comment: Yes for RESTful applications it has become my preferred and default framework. I mainly use 4.3.11 on a day to day basis and I have just started to migrate a few applications over to 5.x

Comment: I'm stuck at 4.* as I'm on a legacy environment (Java 6). I'm now trying to understand how to use Springfox to document APIs using OpenAPI 2. It seems it is not even compatible with Java 6 (despite saying so)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176494/discussion-between-aris-and-lppedd).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, after some research I could not find an out of the box implementation for this approach. In fact, after some consideration my use case example that I though was needing something like this, could be made simpler (thus negating the need for something like that).

Given though, that something like this is imperative, one can actually create a concrete implementation of `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` in which the request can be injected.

With this in hand, the origin of the request can be inspected with the appropriate methods and both the `supportsParameter` and `resolveArgument` can be implemented accordingly.

Given though that a single API may expose information and actions regarding a specific resource I don't see the reason why something like this may be needed.